# (Num (b -> b), Num b) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-systems

I noticed a pattern in Haskell. Usually when I do something wrong

```
[(+3),(-3)] <*> pure 4 :: (Num (b -> b), Num b) => [b]
```

I know the issue is the `(-3)`, which should be `(subtract 3)`, but however the type signature seems to imply at first, that you get a valid value, with some constraints.

`Num b` is logical, there are mathematical operations are involved.
But what does this `Num (b -> b)` mean? The operation `b -> b` is supposed to be a number?

Usually when I notice this, I can imply further arguments to the statement and I get well-typed statements:

```
[(+ 3),(- 3)] <*>  pure 4 4 4 :: (Num (t -> [b]), Num (b -> b), Num t, Num b) => [b]
```

What is happening here?